# how to enforce password in sudoers configuration for user that doesn't have password set?

Tags: linux, bash, authentication, sudo, sudoers

I have a group of users (wheel for example) that I want to add to /etc/sudoers for all commands i.e.:

`%wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL`

In this scenario, if users are set up correctly, everyone in wheel will be prompted for password upon trying to use an elevated command. For any user that does not have a password set (via /etc/shadow), the user will not be prompted for a password and command will succeed....this presents a problem for me. I do not want users with no passwords set to be able to succeed in doing this.

I cannot find a possible way, specifically just through /etc/sudoers, to make any elevated command fail with users with no passwords set. Let me know if I am missing something...

And yes, I know I can approach the problem differently outside of /etc/sudoers (chicken and egg) and know of ways to do it...not question of that though. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'd do `usermod --expiredate 1 user` for all users without a password. That will get their attention and should force a password change before they can login again.

Comment: Not a bad idea in a smaller environment for prevention, but not super practical for my situation, unfortunately.

Comment: Turn on [secure passwords](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-force-users-to-create-secure-passwords-on-linux/) in general?

Comment: Decided to go route of better pam module configuration.